# Hostlistener with Onwindowscroll() for a particular div in the template

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

This is my .html file

```
<table class="table" #scroller  [class.fixed]="fixed">
 <thead>

 </thead>
</table>
```

like this.My requirement is, i want to scroll the table and fix the table header after certain scroll.

My .ts file is this

```
@ViewChild('scroller') scroller: ElementRef
  @HostListener("window:scroll", ['$event'])
   onWindowScroll($event) {
     debugger;
     let num = this.document.body.scrollTop;
      if ( num >50 ) {
      this.fixed = true;
      }else if (this.fixed && num < 5) {
      this.fixed = false;
      }
    }
```

But when i use this all time this windows scroller method is getting activated.i want it to be getting activated while scrolling the table only.so i took the element with Viewchild.The problem is with this code.

```
let num = this.document.body.scrollTop;
```

I am taking the whole document body,i want only the table body scroll event.How can i do it with elementref.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: scrollTop does not exist on htmlcollection error giving sir

Comment: scrollTop does not exist on HtmlCollectionOf<Element> error